# How to add and edit port forwarding rules on text config file?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

The settings on my router can be exported as a .dat file, which is plain text and can be edited and then imported back into the router.
The router's interface is too basic and most settings are not even available, so I am only left with having to add custom settings in this .dat file.

Problem is that I don't know how to add such a complex information (what's the syntax) for port forwarding. The section looks like this:

```
    'PortForwardEnable'='0'
  'PortForwardRules'=''
```

To enable port forwarding it's simple, I just change flag '0' to '1', but the rules I don't know how to add them in a text file.

- SilverCrest (found at LIDL) model SWW 733 A2
- Router seems to have a Mediatek chipset MT7628
- Ralink firmware (RT78A2.V4330.170617)

Thanks.

Comment: Missing information from your question: Make and Model of your Router ...

Comment: It's A SilverCrest SWW 733 A2, from Lidl (http://src.discounto.de/pics/Angebote/2016-09/1777025/2472805_SILVERCREST-WLAN-Verstaerker-SWV-733-A1_xxl.jpg) and I don't know much about it, only what I could get from that .dat file (the platform model).
I also think the firmware is Ralink, because the firmware version is RT78A2.V4330.170617